# Is it possible to host private files on remote file server in Drupal 8?

Tags: files

I want to know, In drupal 8, is there any way to host all private files on remote file server separated from host server.

Files must be uploaded or removed from remote server directly from Drupal site.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the private file system is just another folder on your server, [configured in settings.php](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/file/overview#content-accessing-private-files)

For example, you could

1. Mount a separate storage volume there [via NFS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nfs-mount-on-ubuntu-18-04)
2. Add another [EBS volume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html) (if AWS)